# Pass by reference in C++?

Tags: c++

I am having trouble getting one class to recognize another class exists. I believe this is pass by reference, but I'm not sure.

```
class A{
public: 
A(B b);
};

class B{
public:
B(A a);
};
```

In `class B` the constructor of `B` recognizes I'm passing `A` but in `class A` I keep getting a

> Type 'B' could not be resolved

error.

Comment: To end your confusion: You are not passing by reference, but by value. By reference would look like `A(B &b);` or `A(const B &b);` But as meagar pointed out, that is not the issue here.

Comment: Circles, I hate circles.  How is this ever going to be resolved?  In order to define an instance of B, in the A constructor, the class B must be declared before A.  However, class B needs class A defined first in order to resolve the A in B's constructor.  Please change this design; it's making me dizzy.  If you use pointers or references in your constructor parameters, you could use forward declarations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with "passing", by reference or otherwise.

The issue is that class `B` has not been declared at the point when you try to use it in class `A`.

You need a [forward declaration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) of class `B`:

```
class B;

class A{
public: 
    A(B b);
};

class B{
public:
    B(A a);
};
```

Comment: A forward declaration only works when passing by pointer or reference, so the compiler does not need to know the full type declaration. If you pass by value, it needs to know the full type.  The full declaration of `B` is not known yet when `A` is being declared.  Change the constructor parameter of `A()` to `B &b` instead.  You should do the same for the constructor parameter of `B()`, though `A` is fully declared when `B` is being declared.

Comment: @RemyLebeau A forward declaration will do fine here. The definition is only needed for the constructor definitions.

Comment: I keep getting the error "field has incomplete type 'B'" any ideas why?

Comment: The error *"field has incomplete type"* means that you can't use a forward declaration.  You will need a complete declaration of `class B` before `class A`.  However, the class `B` constructor requires a complete definition of class `A`, so `class A` needs to come first.  Any chance you can redesign this to avoid these cyclic dependencies?